# @angular/http to @angular/common/http

Tags: angular, httpclient, httpmodule

Currently I'm switching from http (@angular/http) to HttpClient (@angular/common/http) and have problems mapping my response to objects.

Old Code

```
getSummary(filters: IFilterParams): Observable<ISummary> {
    return this.http.post('./api/test', filters).pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}
```

What should it be now?

Answer (score 0):

If the response body is a json, you just need to remove the mapping.

```
getSummary(filters: IFilterParams): Observable<ISummary> {
  return this.http.post<ISummary>('./api/test', filters);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: What if it is something like this?   
 this.http.post(`./api/test`, filters, { params }).pipe(map((response: Response) => {        
            this.downloader.download(fileName + ".csv", response.text());
        }));
    }